# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 15)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, openai-gym

I am trying to make a custom Gym Environment so that I can use it in a Keras Network. But there is a problem that is happening to me when I try to fit de neural network.

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_6_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 15)
```

What I understand about this problem is that the states (the inputs that the network receives) are structured as a 3 dimensional array, but I don´t know why.

Here is my init method in the class that defines the environment:

```
def __init__ (self):
    self.action_space = Discrete (4)
    self.observation_space = Box(low=0, high=100, shape=(15,))
    self.state = np.array([1,2,0,3,2,0,4,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,0], dtype=float)
    #self.state = state
    self.length = 15
    self.index = 0
```

After, i initialize two variables that save the shape of the states and the actions, so we can define the model.

```
states = env.observation_space.shape
actions = env.action_space.n

def build_model(states, actions):
model = Sequential()    
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu', input_shape=states))
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
return model
```

The summary of the model:

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 24)                384
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 24)                600
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 100

The last step before the error is when i buid the agent. After that, we call the fit method and occurs the problem.

```
def build_agent(model, actions):
   policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
   memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
   dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, 
              nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
   return dqn

dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

I tried to change the input_shape of the first layer to be (1, 1, 15) but doesn´t seems to work. Maybe the problem is related with the definition of the environment (observation space) or how the environments provides the information to the network. I don´t know...

I hope you can help me. let me know if you need some more information to handle the error.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried changing the input shape to be (1,15)?

Comment: It worked!! First, It returned another error, but it solved quickly adding a Flatten layer at the end of the model. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad to hear it :) I've written up my answer, would be grateful for an 'accept'

Comment: @ManuJiménez: Where exactly did you add the Flatten layer? At the very end after `model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))` or before that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input shape should be (1,15) in your case. This is because the actual input shape is increased by an additional dimension to what you specify in `shape` as keras processes inputs in batches, with the batch size being the first parameter.

The error message is telling you that inputs of shape (1,1,15) are being passed to the model ( i.e. batch of 1, and input shape (1,15), so ndims=3), but you only have ndims=2. Despite only passing (15,) as the input shape, notice that ndims = 2. This is because Keras is adding an additional dimension for the batch.

So to fix, set `shape=(1,15)` which will then be processed as `(1,1,15)` which is what Keras expects.

Comment: I get exactly the same error as the thread poster and I tried your suggested approach by inserting ` input_shape=(1,11)` in the model. Unfortunately I get an error "ValueError: Model output "Tensor("dense_37/BiasAdd:0", shape=(None, 1, 3), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case 3.". Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: You wrote "So to fix, set shape=(1,15) which will then be processed as (1,1,15) which is what Keras expects." --> why will this be processed as (1,1,15) and not as (None, 1, 15)? I thought Keras always adds "None" to the input vector because of the unknown batch size?

Comment: You're correct, but there are two different scenarios here. The first is the 'blueprint' that keras creates for the model, which happens before any data is passed through the model and allows Keras to check that everything fits properly. At this point, the shape is (None, 1, 15). But then during training, with a batch size of 1, this will equate to (1,1,15).

Comment: Thanks ML_Engine for your answer. Why should the batch size be 1? Does this mean we are only using 1 datapoint for the training (which would not make any sense to me)? Further, do you have any idea how I can get rid of the error I get when using your suggested approach "ValueError: Model output "Tensor("dense_37/BiasAdd:0", shape=(None, 1, 3), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case 3."."

Comment: Any comments on my last comment?

Comment: Any comments on my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Why should the batch size be 1? Does this mean we are only using 1 datapoint for the training (which would not make any sense to me)? Further, do you have any idea how I can get rid of the error I get when using your suggested approach "ValueError: Model output "Tensor("dense_37/BiasAdd:0", shape=(None, 1, 3), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case 3."." (here is the whole code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70261352/openai-gym-and-keras-rl-dqn-expects-a-model-that-has-one-dimension-for-each-act)