# OpenAI-Gym and Keras-RL: DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to set a Deep-Q-Learning agent with a custom environment in OpenAI Gym. I have 4 continuous state variables with individual limits and 3 integer action variables with individual limits.

Here is the code:

```
#%% import 
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box, Tuple
import numpy as np


#%%
class Custom_Env(Env):

    def __init__(self):
        
       # Define the state space
       
       #State variables
       self.state_1 = 0
       self.state_2 =  0
       self.state_3 = 0
       self.state_4_currentTimeSlots = 0
       
       #Define the gym components
       self.action_space = Box(low=np.array([0, 0, 0]), high=np.array([10, 20, 27]), dtype=np.int)    
                                                                             
       self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([20, -20, 0, 0]), high=np.array([22, 250, 100, 287]),dtype=np.float16)

    def step(self, action ):

        # Update state variables
        self.state_1 = self.state_1 + action [0]
        self.state_2 = self.state_2 + action [1]
        self.state_3 = self.state_3 + action [2]

        #Calculate reward
        reward = self.state_1 + self.state_2 + self.state_3
       
        #Set placeholder for info
        info = {}    
        
        #Check if it's the end of the day
        if self.state_4_currentTimeSlots >= 287:
            done = True
        if self.state_4_currentTimeSlots < 287:
            done = False       
        
        #Move to the next timeslot 
        self.state_4_currentTimeSlots +=1

        state = np.array([self.state_1,self.state_2, self.state_3, self.state_4_currentTimeSlots ])

        #Return step information
        return state, reward, done, info
        
    def render (self):
        pass
    
    def reset (self):
       self.state_1 = 0
       self.state_2 =  0
       self.state_3 = 0
       self.state_4_currentTimeSlots = 0
       state = np.array([self.state_1,self.state_2, self.state_3, self.state_4_currentTimeSlots ])
       return state

#%% Set up the environment
env = Custom_Env()

#%% Create a deep learning model with keras


from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu', input_shape=states))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions[0] , activation='linear'))
    return model

states = env.observation_space.shape 
actions = env.action_space.shape 
print("env.observation_space: ", env.observation_space)
print("env.observation_space.shape : ", env.observation_space.shape )
print("action_space: ", env.action_space)
print("action_space.shape : ", env.action_space.shape )


model = build_model(states, actions)
print(model.summary())

#%% Build Agent wit Keras-RL
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory

def build_agent (model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit = 50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent (model = model, memory = memory, policy=policy,
                    nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update= 1e-2)
    return dqn

dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics = ['mae'])
dqn.fit (env, nb_steps = 4000, visualize=False, verbose = 1)
```

When I run this code I get the following error message

```
ValueError: Model output "Tensor("dense_23/BiasAdd:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)" has invalid shape. DQN expects a model that has one dimension for each action, in this case (3,).
```

thrown by the line     `dqn = DQNAgent (model = model, memory = memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update= 1e-2)`

Can anyone tell me, why this problem is occuring and how to solve this issue? I assume it has something to do with the built model and thus with the action and state spaces. But I could not figure out what exactly the problem is.

**Reminder on the bounty**: My bounty is expiring quite soon and unfortunately, I still have not received any answer. If you at least have a guess how to tackle that problem, I'll highly appreciate if you share your thoughts with me and I would be quite thankful for it.

Comment: I think keras-rl was integrated into Keras main API and "rl" module is no longer supported. Have you looked at this [code sample](https://keras.io/examples/rl/deep_q_network_breakout/) from Keras?

Comment: @LeonardoSirino: Thanks for your answer. I used similar version of the code for other applications and there I do not encouter any error. I think there is an issue with the dimensionality of the action and state spaces. But I could not figure out what is causing the problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: When I was debugging the code I had the following error: TypeError: Keras symbolic inputs/outputs do not implement __len__. I did a little research and it seems like a problem of version compatibility. I think the old Keras-rl module uses Tensorflow 1.0 behind the scenes and it caused the problem. But since you didn't encountered problems in this other application I'm kind of clueless.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Leonardo. According to your point of view, are the definitions of the states and actions correct? Both as the OpenAI gym components in the  `class Custom_Env(Env)` with `self.action_space = Box(low=np.array([0, 0, 0]), high=np.array([10, 20, 27]), dtype=np.int) ` and `self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([20, -20, 0, 0]), high=np.array([22, 250, 100, 287]),dtype=np.float16)`. And then in the model of Neural Network with `model.add(Dense(actions[0] , activation='linear'))` having `states = env.observation_space.shape` and `actions = env.action_space.shape `?

Comment: @LeonardoSirino: Thanks for your comments. Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: I think the definitions from OpenAI gym are correct, the problem seems to be Keras model. I saw that the output of the model has the shape property, but keras-rl library try to access the output '__len__' in order to validate it. I even tried to skip this verification, but then other problems arise. Anyways, I think this library is deprecated, everything must be inside 'standard Keras' now and should work

Comment: Thanks Leonardo for your answer. You wrote "everything must be inside 'standard Keras' now" --> How can I do that? I tried to import the following 
`from tensorflow.keras import DQNAgent
from tensorflow.keras import BoltzmannQPolicy
from tensorflow.keras import SequentialMemory` but I get the error "ImportError: cannot import name 'DQNAgent' from 'tensorflow.keras'". I also tried to import  `
`from tensorflow import keras
from keras import DQNAgent
from keras import BoltzmannQPolicy
from keras import SequentialMemory` but I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'"

Comment: Would you mind comming up with a suggestion? If you write it as an answer and if it's helpful I will accept the answer (and give you the bounty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we talked about in the comments, it seems that the Keras-rl library is no longer supported (the last update in the repository was in 2019), so it's possible that everything is inside Keras now. I take a look at Keras documentation and there are no high-level functions to build a reinforcement learning model, but is possible to use lower-level functions to this.

- Here is an example of how to use Deep Q-Learning with Keras: [link](https://keras.io/examples/rl/deep_q_network_breakout/)

Another solution may be to downgrade to Tensorflow 1.0 as it seems the compatibility problem occurs due to some changes in version 2.0. I didn't test, but maybe the Keras-rl + Tensorflow 1.0 may work.

There is also a [branch](https://github.com/taylormcnally/keras-rl2) of Keras-rl to support Tensorflow 2.0, the repository is archived, but there is a chance that it will work for you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be totally honest, I don't really understand what you mean by "there are no high-level functions to build a reinforcement learning model, but is possible to use lower-level functions to this". What is the difference between high-level and low-level functions and how can I apply the low-level functions in my case? How can I use them for my code? Furthermore, I used the same approach for another example (e.g. from this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cO5g5qLrLSo). There it works without any problems. Why is it working in some applications and not in others.

Comment: The link you gave me is not useful at all because there they build the agent and the policy from scratch as far as I see it. But I don't want to do this. I just want to use already existing agents because my aim is not improve a general policy but just to apply it.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo for your answer and effort. I awarded the bounty to you. Maybe you can still elaborate a little bit more on my last 2 comments.

Comment: Any comments on my last comments? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Sorry @PeterBe, I've tried to make it work, but I wasn't successful, even skipping the validation to check if the object implements len didn't work, it raised another error in the sequence of the program. What I said about lower-level functions was to implement from scratch, but as you said, this is not your objective. Maybe the last try could be using the original [library](https://pypi.org/project/keras-rl/) with TensorFlow 1.0, but this definitely is not a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Leonardo. Do you know any other library that can be used with OpenAI to solve Reinforcement learning problems like the one I posted above? I would preferably like to use Deep-Q-Learning and SARSA as the solving algorithm.

Comment: I accepted and upvoted your answer. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a flatten layer before the final output can solve this error. Example:

```
def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu', input_shape=states))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(actions[0] , activation='linear'))
    return model
```

Comment: Thanks Garima for your answer (I upvoted it). Actually, I switched from Keras-RL to StableBaselines 3 (https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/) as it seems to have way more mehtods and it is better supported.